# Why is the depth of leaf node a garbage value instead of being one?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

In the [recipes](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#_maximum_depth) section of Tinkerpop/Gremlin the below command is used to compute the depth of a node. This command computes the depth of a node by counting the node itself. However, when we run this command on a leaf node, it returns a garbage value instead of 1. Could someone please clarify regarding this ?

Command:

```
g.V().has('name','F').repeat(__.in()).emit().path().count(local).max()
```

If 'F' is a leaf node then it returns incorrect value. I think it should return 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same data from the [maximum depth recipe](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#_maximum_depth), here are some of the results:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'F').repeat(__.in()).emit().path().count(local).max()
==>5
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'C').repeat(__.in()).emit().path().count(local).max()
==>3
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'A').repeat(__.in()).emit().path().count(local).max()
==>-2147483648
```

We can learn more about the behavior by removing the last couple steps:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'C').repeat(__.in()).emit().path()
==>[v[4],v[6]]
==>[v[4],v[2]]
==>[v[4],v[2],v[0]]
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'A').repeat(__.in()).emit().path()
gremlin>
```

You can see that 'C' has 3 paths and 'A' has 0 paths. This is because all of the traversers were killed before anything was emitted. If you move the `emit()` step before the `repeat()` step, you will get your desired behavior:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'A').emit().repeat(__.in()).path()
==>[v[0]]
gremlin> g.V().has('name', 'A').emit().repeat(__.in()).path().count(local).max()
==>1
```

You can read a more about the `repeat()` step and its interactions with the `emit()` step in the [TinkerPop documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#repeat-step). Specifically, there is a callout box that states:

> If `emit()` is placed after `repeat()`, it is evaluated on the traversers leaving the repeat-traversal. If `emit()` is placed before `repeat()`, it is evaluated on the traversers prior to entering the repeat-traversal.

Comment: awesome works perfectly fine ! but could you please point me to the documentation or other resources, to understand how the change in emit()'s placement worked in this case ? I am trying to understand what you meant by all the traversers were killed before anything was emitted ..

Comment: add more information on `repeat()` and `emit()`. If you think the documentation could use more improvement, please [open an issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/TINKERPOP/issues).